# Association of PDE's with Integral Equations?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, integral-equations

We know the following associations  :

- Volterra Integral Equations $\leftrightarrow$ Initial Value Problems
- Fredholm Integral Equations $\leftrightarrow$ Boundary Value Problems

My questions are :

- Can we associate a partial differential equation with an integral equation, ie can we convert a partial differential equation to an integral equation and **vice-versa** ?
- Can every integral equation be converted to a differential equation ? I have this doubt because the space of integrable functions is much bigger than the space of differentiable functions as we know that continuity is not necessary for integration.

Comment: Most integral equations cannot be turned into differential equations. Take for instance the Fourier transform.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clearer ? I am a newbie in integral equations.

Comment: Well if you have that $g$ is the Fourier transform of $f$, there is no way to get a differential equation that relates the two (that also eliminates the Fourier transform). The reason for this is that the Fourier transform is basically its own inverse.